# Could someone share with me some documentations or sites on how to set up a custom signet using bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, signet

Recently I am going to use bitcoin core to set up a **custom signet** on my docker. I have read some implementations on [wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Signet), but I had some problems when starting up a custom signet. One of the problem is that the mining time I set is not the exactly mining time I got. About this problem you can see it in this [page](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/114425/on-signet-of-bitcoin-core-why-didnt-the-average-time-between-blocks-i-mined-ac), I asked few days ago and no one answered me yet. So I wonder if there are more documentations of the details about setting up a custom signet. I will appreciate it if anyone could help me. THANK YOU!

Comment: Hi, I don't think there's much documentation besides the wiki page you linked to. I suggest to keep things clearly separated and delete the mention of your other question about the mining time, I think this question is only about documentation about custom signet, is it?